# how to parse a dictionary(of string,object) in a asp.net controller

Tags: asp.net, file, fetch-api, multipartform-data

In `asp.net` I have a simple function like this:

```
<HttpPost> Sub SavePortalRecord(ReportID As Integer, JsonInput As Dictionary(Of String, Object), RecordID As Integer?)
```

The problem is that the dictionary's values might be any type. usually a primitive, or a `File`.

Now, when there is no file in the dictionary, I make a simple `post`, and the `dictionary` parses beautifully, everything is perfect.

But once I have a File, I have to use `FormData`, which causes the `dictionary` to mess up. All of a sudden all the values become lists of one item. Instead of just that one item.

I will note that the other parameters in the function do come in correctly. only the dictionary is messed up.

Here is the code I use to send the `post`:

```
export function performAction(controller: string, action: string, vals: Record<string, any>, usePost?: boolean, signal?: AbortSignal) {
    const js = myStringify(vals)
    const hfile = hasFile(vals)
    const url = getActionUrl(controller, action, undefined)
    if (hfile) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const flat = flatten(vals); //this returns a list of keyvaluepairs. this list is correct.
        flat.forEach(x => {
            const val = x[1]
            formData.append(x[0], val)
        })

        const ret = fetchPlus(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            signal
        });
        return ret
    } else {
        return fetchPlus(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: js,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            signal: signal
        });
    }    
}
```

How do I fix this?

I tried 10 different ways of parsing on client side. but the client side seems to be sending correctly. When I log the formData, everything seems correct. But on server side, the dictionary's values are wrong.

Please advise.